# Advertencia: PDOStatement :: execute (): SQLSTATE [HY093]: Número de parámetro no válido: el parámetro no se definió en C:

Tags: pdo

¿Alguien me explica lo que sucede?

```
<?php 
$PDO = new PDO( 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=bd_usuarios;charset=UTF8','root','123' ); 
try {
    echo "datos guardados correctamente";
    $sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO prueba1(nombre, contraseña, email, comentario) VALUES (:nombre, :contraseña, :email, :comentario)");
    $sql->bindParam(':nombre',$_POST['nombre']);
    $sql->bindParam(':contraseña',$_POST['contraseña']);
    $sql->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
    $sql->bindParam(':comentario',$_POST['comentario']);
    $sql->Execute();
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error al guardar los datos:".$e ->GetMessaje();
}
?>
```

Comment: Yo probaría a cambiar el nombre del parámetro `contraseña` por `contrasena` o algo sin caracteres que puedan resultar extraños. Lo mismo digo para el nombre del campo en la base de datos pero, seguramente, con cambiar el nombre del parámetro será suficiente

Comment: Listo, pero ahora resulta que los datos no llegan a la tabla, y actualizo pero nada.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con que no llegan los datos a la tabla? ¿Te da algún error?

Comment: Ninguno. Me marca que los datos se guardaron correctamente, pero voy a la tabla y nada.

Comment: Actualiza el post con lo que tengas ahora