# Enviar formulario html a SQL

Tags: php, sql

¿Alguien me puede explicar el porque un formulario html no llega a la base datos?

O sea, lleno los campos y cuando envió me aparece

> "Datos guardados correctamente"

Y voy a actualizar pero no llega nada. He intentado con diferentes datos y sigue siendo lo mismo.
Les agradecería muchísimo sus aportaciones.

```
<?php 
$PDO = new PDO( 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=bd_usuarios;charset=UTF8','root','123' ); 
try {
    echo "datos guardados correctamente";
    $sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO prueba1(nombre, contraseña, email, comentario) VALUES (:nombre, :contraseña, :email, :comentario)");
    $sql->bindParam(':nombre',$_POST['nombre']);
    $sql->bindParam(':contraseña',$_POST['contraseña']);
    $sql->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
    $sql->bindParam(':comentario',$_POST['comentario']);
    $sql->Execute();
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error al guardar los datos:".$e ->GetMessaje();
}
?>
```

Comment: Añade tu código de otra manera estamos a ciegas y ni idea

Comment: Mateo, el estándar HTML no tiene ningún tipo de relación con SQL. En su forma actual tu pregunta es prácticamente imposible de responder. Si te pones en los zapatos de quien lea tu pregunta, te darías cuenta que, al no tener idea de las herramientas que utilizas, uno se queda en blanco al leerla. Te invito a visitar el centro de ayuda y leer la sección sobre como preguntar. Luego regresa acá, edita la pregunta e incluye la información mínima para hacer de tu pregunta una [buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Advertencia: PDOStatement :: execute (): SQLSTATE \[HY093\]: Número de parámetro no válido: el parámetro no se definió en C:](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201741/advertencia-pdostatement-execute-sqlstate-hy093-n%c3%bamero-de-par%c3%a1metro-n)